# Discussion : Is it ok to approve edits that are adding on to original content?

Tags: discussion, editing

So, is it ok to approve edits that are adding on to original content like following edit ;

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/169154

The added info seems legit and the user couldn't have posted the answer due to low rep. But it seems the same could have achieved using a comment but it may not gain the same visibility as in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question cannot be yes or no. It depends on what the edit is made.
But for your specific case, personally, I would not approve such an edit. The edit should actually be a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too.. I am also not clear what to do after rejecting the edit, should I comment  the edit after rejecting the edit or ask user to do it? For the second case the user may not comment and maybe a valuable info will be lost for the question ..

Comment: just reject it and you shuold be fine.